# How to compare specific items in array inside of basic lodash loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

This is the basic JavaScript for loop I'm trying to replace:

```
for (var i=0; i<tickers.length; i++) {
    if (tickers[i].ticker === selectedTicker) {
        selectTicker('portfolio', tickers[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs) version

```
_.times((tickers.length), function() {
    if (tickers[i].ticker === selectedTicker) {
        selectTicker('portfolio', tickers[i]);
        return;
    }
});
```

Obviously this errors out currently, because there is no `[i]` variable set in the lodash version.

The lodash version is much more readable imho, just do this many times the length of my tickers array.

However I need to compare the ticker of each object to the `selectedTicker`.

---

**UPDATE: Adding screenshot and link to prove to some asking that _lodash is faster than native Javascript.**

http://jsperf.com/forloop-vs-each-from-lodash

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also add the jsperf comparison of `_.find` and `_.filter`/Native `.filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `i` into the callback in the lodash function. This should work:

```
_.times((tickers.length), function(i) {
    if (tickers[i].ticker === selectedTicker) {
      selectTicker('portfolio', tickers[i]);
      return;
    }
});
```

Also, if you're able to use es6 syntax, you can achieve the same result by using `filter`

```
var ticker = tickers.filter(t => t.ticker === selectedTicker)[0];
if(ticker){
  selectTicker('portfolio', ticker);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs#find)

```
var ticker = _.find(tickers, {'ticker': selectedTicker});

// `find()` returns an object if the element is found in array
// it returns `undefined` if not found
if (ticker) {
    // If element found in the array call the function
    selectTicker('portfolio', ticker);

    // return; // To return from the function
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Nice! This found it, however now I need to tell the `selectTicker` function which item in `tickers` to pass in. How would you accomplish that here?

Comment: @LeonGaban The `find` method returns object or `undefined`. You can use `if (foundResult) { selectTicker(foundResult.key) }`. In case, to send more than one elements from object, you can use [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) or [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs#omit)

Comment: Thanks again, I'm trying that now, however it has to loop through all items in my Array before finishing, I want it to stop as soon as the `foundResult` has been found and the next function runs. However `foundResult` always shows true, and the `return` statement doesn't break the loop in this case.

Comment: @LeonGaban You don't need the loop to get the matching object from array, just use `_.find`. Just use `return` after function call.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood, I understand now thanks for the explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an argument to the function:

```
_.times((tickers.length), function( i ) {
    if (tickers[i].ticker === selectedTicker) {
        selectTicker('portfolio', tickers[i]);
        return;
    }
});
```